# Can a conductor be uniformly charged?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, conductors, insulators

I have been reading in books that charges on a conductor resides on its surface and that for a body to be uniformly charged it has to be an insulator.Is it true?If yes does it mean we can consider a spherical conductor as a hollow sphere of the same charge?Can a conductor ever be uniformly charged by any means?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score -1):

You might have a uniform charge density on the surface of a conducting sphere, but inside of a conductor any charge would produce an electric field, and any field wold move free electrons until there was no field. By the way, actually producing a charge density inside of a non-conductor would be a pretty good trick.

Comment: RE "producing a charge density inside of a non-conductor would be a pretty good trick", consider a reverse-biased PN junction diode, for one example.

Comment: I did not understand the last line.Do you mean that it is not possible to have an insulator which has charge inside?

Comment: It might be possible, but how would you go about distributing a charge throughout the interior of a non-conductor?

Comment: I forgot to qualify my original answer.  A conductor (or semi-conductor) being powered to carry a current would tend to have a positive charge density toward one end and a negative charge density toward the other.